# Mock request object not working for tests in node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, jasmine

I have a module for checking the authorization with session.  It's a really simple script thats reads the session and returns true or false if the user is logged in.  This is my script:

```
module.exports = {

    check: function(req) {
        return (
            req.session && 
            req.session.swipe && 
            req.session.swipe === true
        );
    }
}
```

The `check()` functiongets a request object as a parameter and then reads the session object in it.

I wanted to test it with Jasmine to make sure it returns the correct boolean.  This is the spec:

```
var Auth = require('../controllers/auth');

describe("Authorization", function(){

    it("should grant access", function(next) {

        var request  = {
            session: {
                swipe: true
            }
        };


        var value = Auth.check(request);

        expect(request.session.swipe).toBeDefined();
        expect(value).toBe(true);

    });


    it("should deny access", function(next) {

        var request  = {
            session: {
                swipe: false
            }
        };

        var value = Auth.check(request);
        expect(request.session.swipe).toBeDefined();
        expect(value).toBe(false);

    });

});
```

When this runs with the server the request object is generated by express, but in tests I wanted to create a mock with the session variable only.  When I run the tests, jasmine outputs the following:
[image: Jasmine Output]

I don't know where's the problem, but I suppose it's with the request object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has a simple solution. Either call next at the end of each function passed to it(), or pass it() a function with no parameters. This will work:

```
var Auth = require('./con');

describe("Authorization", function(){

    it("should grant access", function(next) {

        var request  = {
            session: {
                swipe: true
            }
        };


        var value = Auth.check(request);

        expect(request.session.swipe).toBeDefined();
        expect(value).toBe(true);
        next();  // <----------- added next()

    });


    it("should deny access", function(next) {

        var request  = {
            session: {
                swipe: false
            }
        };

        var value = Auth.check(request);
        expect(request.session.swipe).toBeDefined();
        expect(value).toBe(false);
        next() // <----------- added next()

    });

});
```

as well as this

```
var Auth = require('./con');

describe("Authorization", function(){

    it("should grant access", function() {// <----------- removed next

        var request  = {
            session: {
                swipe: true
            }
        };


        var value = Auth.check(request);

        expect(request.session.swipe).toBeDefined();
        expect(value).toBe(true);

    });


    it("should deny access", function() {  // <----------- removed next

        var request  = {
            session: {
                swipe: false
            }
        };

        var value = Auth.check(request);
        expect(request.session.swipe).toBeDefined();
        expect(value).toBe(false);

    });

});
```